# Install metric-sever in EKS

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I'm trying to install [metric-server](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server) in Amazon EKS.  Server is version 1.24 and kubectl version 1.25.

Here is the result:

```
 kubectl apply -f https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/releases/latest/download/components.yaml
Warning: resource serviceaccounts/metrics-server is missing the kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration annotation which is required by kubectl apply. kubectl apply should only be used on resources created declaratively by either kubectl create --save-config or kubectl apply. The missing annotation will be patched automatically.
serviceaccount/metrics-server configured
Warning: resource clusterroles/system:aggregated-metrics-reader is missing the kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration annotation which is required by kubectl apply. kubectl apply should only be used on resources created declaratively by either kubectl create --save-config or kubectl apply. The missing annotation will be patched automatically.
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:aggregated-metrics-reader configured
Warning: resource clusterroles/system:metrics-server is missing the kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration annotation which is required by kubectl apply. kubectl apply should only be used on resources created declaratively by either kubectl create --save-config or kubectl apply. The missing annotation will be patched automatically.
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:metrics-server configured
Warning: resource rolebindings/metrics-server-auth-reader is missing the kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration annotation which is required by kubectl apply. kubectl apply should only be used on resources created declaratively by either kubectl create --save-config or kubectl apply. The missing annotation will be patched automatically.
rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/metrics-server-auth-reader configured
Warning: resource clusterrolebindings/metrics-server:system:auth-delegator is missing the kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration annotation which is required by kubectl apply. kubectl apply should only be used on resources created declaratively by either kubectl create --save-config or kubectl apply. The missing annotation will be patched automatically.
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/metrics-server:system:auth-delegator configured
Warning: resource clusterrolebindings/system:metrics-server is missing the kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration annotation which is required by kubectl apply. kubectl apply should only be used on resources created declaratively by either kubectl create --save-config or kubectl apply. The missing annotation will be patched automatically.
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:metrics-server configured
Warning: resource services/metrics-server is missing the kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration annotation which is required by kubectl apply. kubectl apply should only be used on resources created declaratively by either kubectl create --save-config or kubectl apply. The missing annotation will be patched automatically.
service/metrics-server configured
Warning: resource deployments/metrics-server is missing the kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration annotation which is required by kubectl apply. kubectl apply should only be used on resources created declaratively by either kubectl create --save-config or kubectl apply. The missing annotation will be patched automatically.
Warning: resource apiservices/v1beta1.metrics.k8s.io is missing the kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration annotation which is required by kubectl apply. kubectl apply should only be used on resources created declaratively by either kubectl create --save-config or kubectl apply. The missing annotation will be patched automatically.
apiservice.apiregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1.metrics.k8s.io configured
The Deployment "metrics-server" is invalid: spec.template.spec.containers[0].ports[1].name: Duplicate value: "https"
```

I've read the FAQ and Known issues section.

I'm worried about "the deployment is invalid" message.
Any workdaround?

**UPDATE 1**:

```
curl -L https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/releases/latest/download/components.yaml
```

results in:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: metrics-server
  name: metrics-server
  namespace: kube-system
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: metrics-server
    rbac.authorization.k8s.io/aggregate-to-admin: "true"
    rbac.authorization.k8s.io/aggregate-to-edit: "true"
    rbac.authorization.k8s.io/aggregate-to-view: "true"
  name: system:aggregated-metrics-reader
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - metrics.k8s.io
  resources:
  - pods
  - nodes
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: metrics-server
  name: system:metrics-server
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - nodes/metrics
  verbs:
  - get
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - pods
  - nodes
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: metrics-server
  name: metrics-server-auth-reader
  namespace: kube-system
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: extension-apiserver-authentication-reader
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: metrics-server
  namespace: kube-system
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: metrics-server
  name: metrics-server:system:auth-delegator
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: system:auth-delegator
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: metrics-server
  namespace: kube-system
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: metrics-server
  name: system:metrics-server
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: system:metrics-server
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: metrics-server
  namespace: kube-system
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: metrics-server
  name: metrics-server
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  ports:
  - name: https
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: https
  selector:
    k8s-app: metrics-server
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: metrics-server
  name: metrics-server
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: metrics-server
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 0
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: metrics-server
    spec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - --cert-dir=/tmp
        - --secure-port=4443
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
        - --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP,ExternalIP,Hostname
        - --kubelet-use-node-status-port
        - --metric-resolution=15s
        image: k8s.gcr.io/metrics-server/metrics-server:v0.6.2
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        livenessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /livez
            port: https
            scheme: HTTPS
          periodSeconds: 10
        name: metrics-server
        ports:
        - containerPort: 4443
          name: https
          protocol: TCP
        readinessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /readyz
            port: https
            scheme: HTTPS
          initialDelaySeconds: 20
          periodSeconds: 10
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 200Mi
        securityContext:
          allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
          readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
          runAsNonRoot: true
          runAsUser: 1000
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /tmp
          name: tmp-dir
      nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/os: linux
      priorityClassName: system-cluster-critical
      serviceAccountName: metrics-server
      volumes:
      - emptyDir: {}
        name: tmp-dir
---
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
apiVersion: apiregistration.k8s.io/v1
kind: APIService
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: metrics-server
  name: v1beta1.metrics.k8s.io
spec:
  group: metrics.k8s.io
  groupPriorityMinimum: 100
  insecureSkipTLSVerify: true
  service:
    name: metrics-server
    namespace: kube-system
  version: v1beta1
  versionPriority: 100
```

```
  k top nodes
Error from server (ServiceUnavailable): the server is currently unable to handle the request (get nodes.metrics.k8s.io)
```

Comment: What does kubectl top nodes show?

Comment: Looks like you have a duplicate https port. can you post the template here please?

Comment: @RichardRublev I have posted the requested info.

Comment: @sai I have posted the requested info.

Answer (score 1):

I can tell you what worked for me on minikube,I am not 100% sure that is going to work on EKS.
You must edit

```
 kubectl edit deployment/metrics-server -n kube-system
```

add this line

```
- --metric-resolution=15s
- --kubelet-insecure-tls <- THIS LINE MUST BE ADDED
image: k8s.gcr.io/metrics-server
```

Check again with

```
kubectl top nodes
```

Be aware that you have disabled TLS,which is not may be the best option but it works in my case.
You can read [secure kubernetes metrics](https://www.brightbox.com/blog/2020/09/15/secure-kubernetes-metrics/),one other way to secure the metrics server.

Answer (score 0):

I have deleted all stuff related with metrics server and applied:

```
kubectl apply -f https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/releases/latest/download/components.yaml
```

and it now works.